# Can't get the Google Map div fixed

Tags: css, google-maps, html

I'm trying to get the Google Map div fixed so it becomes always visible, but somehow the style property "position:fixed" is not working. The code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
    #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

           Some script

      </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
     <div class="nav">

            First div

     </div>
     <div id="artistList">

            Second div

     </div>
     <div id="map_canvas" style="position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%">

            Map div

     </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help? Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

This will solve it:

```
<div id="fixed" style="position:fixed; top:0">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    [map content goes here]
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up your code a little to make things more visible. At first you should move the css style settings from your `map_canvas` into your css section in the html head. What remains is a clean `<div id="map_canvas"></div>`. Now let's head to your CSS section in the html head. Try it like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html {}
body {margin: 0px; padding: 10px }
#map_canvas {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    margin:10px;
}
</style>
```

I removed the `height:100%;` from `html` and `body`. I reduced to sizes of the canvas from 100% to 90% and gave it a red border and a margin of 10px to make things more clear. The div is set in the upper right corner now and is fixed. I tested it on FF, Chrome, Safari and IE.

But now one little question... Does it make sense to make the canvas 100% wide and high?! The map_canvas would hide everything else in your html...?

Comment: Thanks for the response! But it still doesn't work for me. Now the map never show up and I can only see one red line on top. I'm doing this in a Grails .gsp and I'm new to this, so perhaps there's something else that I don't know.

Comment: About your question. My point is to have a map on the background of the page and always visible and then other divs that overlay the map. I managed to do this overlay successful by doing: position:absolute; and  z-index: 1;

Answer (score 0):

Najeeb's solution did not work for me.

Changing the map elements css (from position:absolute to position:fixed) after the "tilesloaded" map event seemed to work.